# Is it possible to play in tablet mode on a Lenovo Yoga 7?

Tags: genshin-impact

I got a Lenovo Yoga 7 and recently downloaded Genshin Impact after not playing for a few months.

I was wondering if Genshin Impact supported Tablet mode for this model, as keyboard is hard for me to get used to, and I might not always have a mouse available.

Can I play on my computer as if it were mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Genshin Impact on Windows does not supports touch controls, only the Android and iOS versions have such feature.